# Android StreetViewFragment - set StreetViewSource

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-street-view

Is it possible with StreetView SDK for Android set the source of the street view data to "OUTDOOR"? I didn't found this setting anywhere.

Something like this for Javascript: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewSource?

I'm using in the app [SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment)

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The feature request for StreetViewSource was handled at

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69047818

Recently in March 2018 it was marked as Fixed, so the Play Services 12.0.0 now have this feature.

The announcement was made in Release notes as well:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases#march_20_2018

There are the following methods in StreetViewPanorama class

`public void setPosition (LatLng position, int radius, StreetViewSource source)`

`public void setPosition (LatLng position, StreetViewSource source)`

Sources:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/StreetViewPanorama

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/StreetViewSource

I hope you find this information useful.